# Clarification about WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask

Tags: watchos, watchconnectivity

In Apple's sample project [SimpleWatchConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/using_watch_connectivity_to_communicate_between_your_apple_watch_app_and_iphone_app) there is a comment saying

> WKWatchConnectivityRefreshBackgroundTask should be completed – Otherwise they will keep consuming
> the background executing time and eventually causes an app crash.
> The timing to complete the tasks is when the current WCSession turns to not .activated or
> hasContentPending flipped to false (see completeBackgroundTasks), so KVO is set up here to observe
> the changes if the two properties

My question is: Is this *always* the case for timing the call on `completeBackgroundTasks` (KVO on hasContentPending/activation)? Shouldn't I try to defer `completeBackgroundTasks` until I have done all the work that normally happens when I receive data over WatchConnectivity?

Comment: Furthermore, if this comment holds true in all cases, why didn't they just make this happen automatically? If I SHOULD wait for my WC receivers to do their work, I wonder why Apple didn't put a completion callback into those receivers so this can happen automatically. So frustrating. >:/